# Unable to view a subtitle in mpv

Tags: configuration, mpv, video-subtitles

I have a subtitle that is in .vtt format. I can see the subtitle in l3afpad or any text editor but am unable to play that specific subtitle in MPV. I looked through all of https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#keyboard-control but can't figure it out.

Also seems mpv -vvv no longer works

```
$ mpv -vvv Open\ World\ Terraforming\ Survival\ _\ Planet\ Crafter\ Gameplay\ _\ Part\ 5\ \[tHcbTkGNVHg\].webm 
Error parsing option vvv (option not found)
Setting commandline option --vvv= failed.
Exiting... (Fatal error)
```

This is the configuration of my mpv -

```
~/.config/mpv$ cat mpv.conf
alang=eng,en,english
slang=en,eng, english
sub-scale=1.00
save-position-on-quit
```

On VLC, the subtitle plays fine.

It does load the subtitle, just fails to show it :(

```
$ mpv Open\ World\ Terraforming\ Survival\ _\ Planet\ Crafter\ Gameplay\ _\ Part\ 5\ \[tHcbTkGNVHg\].webm 
Resuming playback. This behavior can be disabled with --no-resume-playback.
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (vp9 1280x720 30.000fps)
 (+) Subs  --sid=1 --slang=en 'Open World Terraforming Survival _ Planet Crafter Gameplay _ Part 5 [tHcbTkGNVHg].en.srt' (subrip) (external)
VO: [gpu] 1280x720 yuv420p
V: 00:52:40 / 02:46:12 (32%)
Saving state.

Exiting... (Quit)
```

Doing -

```
$ ffmpeg -v error -i Open\ World\ Terraforming\ Survival\ _\ Planet\ Crafter\ Gameplay\ _\ Part\ 5\ \[tHcbTkGNVHg\].webm -f null - 2>error.log
```

Gives no output, nothing happens :( . An error log is generated but it is empty.

Any hints or ideas most welcome.

Comment: You can try to check if the file is OK with command `ffmpeg -v error -i file.webm -f null - 2>error.log`. Probably `vlc` just skip some inconsistency and continue the playback.

Comment: Updated with your workaround, still issue persists and ffmpeg doesn't show any errors. Have updated what I did in the main question itself.

Comment: In this case seems to me like a bug in the software.  My humble recommendation will be to view this episode with `vlc` and continue further :)

Comment: Actually did that and was able to view it without an issue. I tried other videos and they worked fine with mpv, dunno if it's length of the video or what that is the issue. The subtitle was webvtt although from what I gather lot of features of webvtt are not used by google.

Comment: The video was approximately of 3 hrs from youtube. Others are much shorter and they continue playint file in mpv.

Answer (score 1):

You can add in command line `--sub-file` to add subtitles:

```
 mpv --sub-file=/path/to/subtitle/file  Open\ World\ Terraforming\ Survival\ _\ Planet\ Crafter\ Gameplay\ _\ Part\ 5\ \[tHcbTkGNVHg\].webm
```

If you want verbose output to console use `-v -v -v` instead of `-vvv`

Comment: The subtitle file loads but doesn't show anything. Still I would try your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: I have updated the question so it better tells what happens. Thank you for attempting.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had difficulties with viewing external subtitles in mpv.
I tried convert subs vtt to srt with online tools but no displayed converted subs in mpv.

After adding ".en" or any other pair of letters (".xx" are fine, without quotes, of course) to filename subtitles are displayed as supposed (if whey supported by operational system - Arabic, Cyrrillic, Hindi, Japanese, Korean, Thai etc.).

I hope this comment will be helpful.